# error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateBootstr apper" task could not be loaded

Tags: c#, .net, command-line-interface, build-error

I was trying to publish a dotnet console application via CLI and ran into this problem don't know what to do help me out

The CLI I entered

```
``dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained true -r win10-x86 -p:PublishSingleFile=True
```

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(6027,5): error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateBootstr
apper" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a
3a.  Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains
 a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [F:\tp\app\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj]
```